# Error occurred while copying resources/android/icon/mdpi-foreground.png

Tags: android, android-studio, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am getting following error while copying icons and splash screen using `cordova-res`.

**I am using capacitor to build the app**

I am using following command to copy the icons:

```
cordova-res android --skip-config --copy
```

here is the response of the command:

```
~/Public/accountech-ecommerce/ionic-files$ cordova-res android --skip-config --copy
Generated 18 resources for Android
WARN:   Error occurred while copying resources/android/icon/mdpi-foreground.png
WARN:   Error occurred while copying resources/android/icon/mdpi-background.png
WARN:   Error occurred while copying resources/android/icon/hdpi-foreground.png
WARN:   Error occurred while copying resources/android/icon/hdpi-background.png
WARN:   Error occurred while copying resources/android/icon/xhdpi-foreground.png
WARN:   Error occurred while copying resources/android/icon/xhdpi-background.png
WARN:   Error occurred while copying resources/android/icon/xxhdpi-foreground.png
WARN:   Error occurred while copying resources/android/icon/xxhdpi-background.png
WARN:   Error occurred while copying resources/android/icon/xxxhdpi-foreground.png
WARN:   Error occurred while copying resources/android/icon/xxxhdpi-background.png
Copied 31 resource items to Android
```

PS: I have followed this instruction to do that: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/splash-screens-and-icons

Answer (score 92, accepted):

I ran into the same error in a new Ionic Capacitor@2.4.7 project. I had the `splash.png` and `icon.png` in the `resources` directory. But those aren't enough. The error is related to the [Adaptive Icons](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-res#adaptive-icons) section for `cordova-res`. 2 more icons are missing in your `resources` directory.

1. Add the required `icon-foreground.png` and `icon-background.png` to the `resources/android` directory
2. (Optional) Check if `cordova-res` is the latest. For me I upgraded to version 0.15.3 on a mac with this commands: `sudo npm -g remove cordova-res` and then `sudo npm -g install cordova-res --unsafe-perm`
3. Re-run the command:

```
cordova-res android --skip-config --copy
```

- Successful output now looks like (the 18 changed to 24):

```
Generated 24 resources for Android
Copied 31 resource items to Android
```

Comment: It seems it doesn't work anymore, even with the latest Cordova-res.
No error, no missing files, but just the same warnings and still 18 images generated.

Comment: Any idea on what are the required dimensions of these images?

Comment: You may have to remove your android and resources/android directories. Then `npx cap add android`. Then `cordova-res android --skip-config --copy`.

Answer (score 35):

The files should be organized like this:

```
resources/
├── android/
│   ├── icon-background.png
│   └── icon-foreground.png
├── icon.png
└── splash.png
```

Next, run this command to generate all images then copy them into the native projects:

```
 cordova-res ios --skip-config --copy
 cordova-res android --skip-config --copy
```

Answer (score 16):

The following steps worked for me.

you will need to create two images manually.

**Step 1**

Create a 432x432 .png file. Then save it as "icon-background.png". you may decide to make the color transparent or not

In my case, I created a white image since I need a white background for my icon and I went for the 432x432 dimension.

**Step 2**

Create another  432x432 .png file and save it as "icon-foreground.png".

In this case, you will be mindful of the color of the background you use in the first image.

**Step 3**

put the two images created above into *`<Project Directory>/resources/android/`*

**Step 4**

then run either of the following from the project directory, depending on whichever works for you. number 1 worked for me.

1. *`cd android && gradlew assembleDebug && cd ..`*
2. *`ionic cordova run android`*

Comment: what do you mean with "you will be mindful of the color of the background you use in the first image" ??

Comment: it has to be a contrasting color. if the background color is white, then icon-foreground.png image should either be black or something that is visible when placed on top of white color

Answer (score 1):

I followed the instructions on this video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Ce09by4qFE

You basically have to go in to Android Studio and create a new image resource/whatever it's called.

It all used to work with a CLI command. Not anymore... (at least for me)

Answer (score 0):

Directly ADD your android application via android studio
go to APP
then click **file > new > image asset**
now set your app icon manually

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29773956)

Comment: That will not replace the splash screen.

Comment: yes , but splash screen added  by ionic command and after you got this error  for app icon that time this is helpful .throw this you direct change your app icon. @JohnHarris

Answer (score 0):

I solved by using capacitor-assets, which has an "Easy Mode".
For example in my ionic-vue android project I used:

```
npx capacitor-assets generate --android --assetPath resources/android --androidProject android
```

if you don't have it installed, you can do it by typing:

```
npm install @capacitor/assets -g
```

Answer (score -4):

If you using ionicframework try this 
`ionic cordova resources [<platform>] [options]`

[ionic cordova resources](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-resources)

Comment: Since I am using `capacitorjs`, getting this error: `[ERROR] Could not find cordova integration in the default project.`